# How to in this Reactjs file get images height and width before using an array

Tags: reactjs

I learns Reactjs and trying to get images height and widths in this file to calculate the Ratio.

I havet this file albumData.js that looks like this:

```
// WEEK 1
import photo11 from '../images/weeks/1/DlGoaxEX0AAjY-7.jpg'
import photo12 from '../images/weeks/1/4olpqsvfte5rubn47j936z7c5vn9lff.jpeg'
import photo13 from '../images/weeks/1/9tlnx2sudu05jqxwij2evyvaifkrvbc.jpeg'

// WEEK 2
import photo21 from '../images/weeks/2/2.jpg'
import photo23 from '../images/weeks/2/original.jpg'
import photo22 from '../images/weeks/2/1_vtY9uCjeKSa1jIXm504jlg.jpeg.jpg'

export const albums = [
    {
        route: "1",
        id: "album1",
        data: [
            { id: "week 1-1", key: "1", backgroundImage: photo11, ratio: 768/1024, background: "rgb(56, 230, 236)", title: "week 1", description: "some desc" },
            { id: "week 1-2", key: "2", backgroundImage: photo12, ratio: 0.66771819137, background: "rgb(56, 230, 236)", title: "week 1", description: "some desc" },
            { id: "week 1-3", key: "3", backgroundImage: photo13, ratio: 0.74973711882, background: "rgb(56, 230, 236)", title: "week 1", description: "some desc" },
        ]
    },
    {
        route: "2",
        id: "album2",
        data: [
            { id: "week 2-1", key: "1", backgroundImage: photo21, ratio: 0.75, background: "rgb(56, 230, 236)", title: "week 2", description: "some desc" },
            { id: "week 2-2", key: "2", backgroundImage: photo22, ratio: 0.75, background: "rgb(56, 230, 236)", title: "week 2", description: "some desc" },
            { id: "week 2-3", key: "3", backgroundImage: photo23, ratio: 0.56145833333, background: "rgb(56, 230, 236)", title: "week 2", description: "some desc" },
        ]
    }
    ]
```

I call it from different locations like this

```
import { albums } from '../albumData'
```

My problem that I can't solve is that I need to input the images `ratio` inside the `export const albums`

Before I call and use the `import { albums } from '../albumData'` the array `data` in `albums` must have the `ratio` filled in from the actual images `imports`. I do that manually now but there will be 10.000 images.

The image Ratio is the width divided by the height!

I tried using React hooks but think that require a function something. Is there some static way in React to run this before using the `albums`?

Please advice